# rscript 4.1.0 commandArgs asValue ends with unused argument

Tags: r

I run the following code

```
cmd <- commandArgs(asValues=TRUE)
```

by the command line:

```
rscript .\CLArgs.r --dsdq=dfsffsfsd
```

and get the following output

```
Error in commandArgs(asValues = TRUE) : 
   unused argument (asValues = TRUE)
Execution stopped
```

I also try with

```
cmd <- commandArgs(asValue=TRUE)
```

to be compliant with the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/R.utils/versions/2.10.1/topics/commandArgs)

The following code runs well

```
cmd <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
```

But I more interested in asValue.

What do I do wrong ?

Comment: `asValue` isn't an argument ot `commandArgs`. Look at the documentation `help(commandArgs)`. It is not clear what you are trying to achieve with `asValue`, meaning a meaningful answer is not possible.

Comment: I think you want to use `R.utils::commandArgs` but you are using `base::commandArgs`

Comment: @RonakShah I think you are right, but how do I switch to R.utils ?

Comment: `install.packages('R.utils')` to install the package and then ensure it is loaded using `require(R.utils)` or `library(R.utils)`. The latter has to be done in every time you open R.

Comment: I can only grant one answer but feel free to make one I will +1 both